# Representing set of vectors in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

A problem in my book asks us to show that two  vector sets ***S***<sub>1</sub> = {(1, 2, -1), (0, 1, 1), (2, 5, -1)} and ***S***<sub>2</sub> = {(-2, -6, 0), (1, 1, -2)} have the same span. My book solved this by putting the vectors into matrices as follows:

\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\0&1&1\\2&5&-1\end{bmatrix}
and
\begin{bmatrix}-2&-6&0\\1&1&-2\end{bmatrix}

They then reduced the matrices to reduced row echelon form, and drew the conclusion that the sets have the same span because the reduced matrices are the same.

I'm just a little confused on why this means they have the same span -- what is reducing the matrices to row echelon form doing, exactly? What does the row-echelon form of a matrix of vectors represent? Previously my book has worked with coefficient/augmented matrices to find a solution of a system of equations, not with matrices of vectors.

I'm also confused on why they put the vectors from the set into a matrix -- is that valid thing you can do? My book previously stated that you can represent a *single* vector as a 1 x n matrix -- does the same idea apply here with multiple vectors? They've never actually used this practice previously in the book or in any examples, so I'm a little confused as to how it's being used in this problem.

Comment: First part of this problem. Can you verify that the three given vectors in $S_1$ are linear dependent or independent? Because I see some trouble in the exercise here...

Comment: They have to be dependent if S1 and S2 span the same subspace, but I don't think my book uses that in their solution?

Comment: Are the 3 vectors in $S_1$ lin dependent?

Comment: They have to be, right?

Comment: But...are they?

Comment: Check the determinant

Comment: Wait, what's the trouble you see in the exercise? Cause I just want to understand the way my book did it haha

Comment: I think that the determinant of $S_1$ is not zero, and so I am not so sure that both vectorsets  have the same span...

Comment: Ahhh, I made an error in one of the vectors. I edited my original post

Comment: Elementary row operations don't change the span of the set of rows (you should think about why this is – it's important to understand it). Therefore, you are looking at the same span after you get to reduced row echelon form as before you started reducing (since you can carry out the reduction using elementary row operations), so comparing the two reduced forms is the same as comparing the two original spans.

Comment: @dagny On a side note, is it now also clear in your pre-edited post that both vector sets could impossibly have the same span?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, this makes sense! So I guess I don't have to worry about whether or not vectors can be represented in matrices in general, it just happens to work in this problem?

Comment: @imranfat yep it does

Comment: A matrix is a rectangular array of numbers. A vector is a line of numbers. You can interpret the rows of a matrix as vectors. You can interpret the columns of a matrix as numbers. You don't have to, but sometimes it's useful/convenient to do so.